# Error in my plugin with wp_mail function ()

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing my first plugin in Wordpress. Then one of the functions need to send an email.

But when I call the function **wp_mail ()** throws me this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_mail ()**

How should I define this function in my plugin??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to do something before loading the WordPress enviroment.

All of your actions should be attached to some hook, for instance "init" for actions on the front-end, "admin-init" on the backend, or "wp-ajax-{$your-action-here}" for ajax.

Check the codex docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters

Answer (score 0):

Just include wp-load.php and go ahead!

```
require('../../../wp-load.php');
```

or

```
require('wp-load.php');
```

Depending how your script are loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The `wp_mail()` function is not available until after the action `plugins_loaded`, so if you try to use it before that point it will throw an error because the function is undefined at that point.

So rather than simply calling `wp_mail()`, you should be hooking that process to an action so that it occurs after the function has been loaded.

A lot of plugins use `init` as the action hook to connect their action to.  `init` comes after `plugins_loaded`, so if you use that, it should work.

Comment: wp_mail() is not a plugin , it is  Pluggable Function ! situated in "wp-includes\pluggable.php " , and it will not work , till wp_config.php it will be loaded !

Comment: While that is a correct statement, calling wp_config.php in your plugin is not the proper way of making sure that wp_mail is available for use.  The correct way is to make sure that whatever process you are using wp_mail in happens *after* the plugins_loaded action, at which time wp_mail would be loaded by either another plugin OR by inclusion from pluggable.php.